# Hibernate Reverse Engineering to generate annotated POJO classes from database tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, ant

I am using ant script for Hibernate Reverse Engineering to generate annotated POJO classes from database tables. In this process, I want to write all details like name of each table and generated class etc. on console.
Can you help me with this?

```
<target name="gen_hibernate" description="Generate Hibernate POJO classes with prefix 'Gen'">                                        
               <hibernatetool >                        
                       <classpath path="${build.dir}/classes"/>
                       <jdbcconfiguration                                
                               configurationfile="${appdir}/generate/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml"
                               revengfile="${appdir}/generate/hibernate/hibernate.reveng.xml"
                               packagename="com.pojo.generated"                                                                        
                               detectmanytomany="true"        
                               detectoptimisticlock="true"                                
                               />
</hibernatetool>
</target>
```

Comment: Which ant task you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

You should try [MinuteProject](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/) , it has a very nice JPA2 reverse engineering tool and also a a spring + hibernate layer if you want.

Comment: I want to generate only by using hibernate jars.

Comment: There is a version of JPA 2 reverse engineering ..which generate the entities for you ! Pure JPA2 ..independent of the implementation Eclipse Link or Hibernate...